# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a problem inserting data into a table on a MySQL database using a VB.NET application. The function will add the text box data into attendance database, unfortunately it show error when I click the button.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim Mydate = New DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day, 9, 0, 0, 0)
    textdateTxt.Text = Mydate
    Try
        Dim Query1 As String = "INSERT INTO employee.attendance（empID,empName,empDepartment） VALUES （@empID,@empName,@empDepartment)"

        Dim COMMAND As New MySqlCommand(Query1, MysqlConn)




        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", idLB.Text)
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empName", empNameLB.Text)
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empDepartment", empDepartmentTxt.Text)


        MysqlConn.Open()
        COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error Connecting To Database")
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'empName,empDepartment） VALUES （'S001','BAN','System')' at line 1

Comment: Are you sure that is the real code used?  Is `EmpId` really a text field? Is 'BAN' and 'System' really what was on the form?

Comment: Yes, 'BAN' and 'System' was retrieved from  employeeDetail database when the user login and it will display on the interface text box. This button will get this three text box from interface and store into attendance database.

Comment: That error looks more like it came from code concatenating SQL, that code is using Parameters like it should though.

Comment: okay....May I know any idea to solve it?

Comment: I cant see anything wrong with the SQL.  I would use `Add` rather than `addWithValue` but  a problem there would give a different message.  I'd also use a new Connection like you should, and then dispose it and the command object.  But those ought not cause a SQL syntax error

Comment: That error didn't come from the code as you are displaying a different message in your catch block. You should display the ex.message instead. Regardless of what happens exceptionwise you would only ever receive `error connecting to database` which is going to be very confusing when it has nothing to do with a connection.

Comment: YES. The problem has solved. The root cause is due to the spacing " employee.attendance（empID " between attendance and the bracket . After I changed it to employee.attendance(empID then solved. Thank all and thank god...the problem was solved and wasted my whole afternoon time.